# not able to run Node in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, bash, visual-studio-code

I installed node, bash and Visual studio Code on my windows 10 environment laptop.
I'm able to successfully **run bash --version** and **node --version** from the command line

but when I try to run the JavaScript file with the following command **code object.js**, I get the following error

***bash: code: command not found***

Any idea what I can do to get this working in visual studio code?

Comment: I make my bet: 'code' is not in `$PATH` variable, and should be

Comment: By editing `~/.bashrc`